# Regex to match partial or full string

Tags: regex, hive

I am relatively new to writing regex and want to seek some help for that.

My sample data is:

```
30/11/2018 M11362019           00 CIN VALIDATION       8888880000019781                                         OK
 08:34:32   84682309               246061434674072601
 P2P        84682309               246061434674072601
 DETAILS: ABC/ABC SFX : M11362019            00


 30/11/2018 M11362019           00 BAL ENQ(HOME PAGE)   8888880000019781            177.00                       OK
 08:34:34   84682309               246061434674074158
 P2P        84682309               246061434674074158
```

Now I am trying to break this into columns using hive regex commands and do further analysis. Ideally I want to capture all the DETAILS into one column for convenience since its contents are pretty dynamic.

The regex I came up with is:

```
((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/](19|20)\d\d) ([^\s]+\s*)(00) ([a-zA-Z0-9() ]*) ([0-9. ]*) ([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*)\n( [0-9:]*) (\s*[0-9:]*) (\s*[0-9]*) ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\n( [a-zA-Z0-9_]*) (\s*[0-9]*) (\s*[0-9]*)([a-zA-Z ]*)(\n( DETAILS:[a-zA-Z0-9:,.\-/ ]*)\n [a-zA-Z0-9:,.\-$/ ]*)
```

However, this captures cases only when details are present whereas I want to treat "details" only as an optional field. Could you suggest me a workaround for this?

Comment: Try adding `?` at the end of your pattern.

Comment: U mean instead of * at the end? That doesn't seem to work. It is not capturing the details part then